# Zebra TLP 2844 prinst only limited number of labels

Tags: zebra-printers

I am trying to print 20 labels. The printer prints 10, 12, 15 labels and sometime 17 but not 20. It works fine if I send 10 labels and then 10 again. But why it wont print 20? Is there any maximum for printing labels?

Comment: Your question is too vague. It sounds like you could be having port handshaking issues. This sounds like a question you should direct to the technical support group at Zebra.

Comment: I was just wondering if there is a limit on how many labels can the printer print at a time. I am going to wait if someone else had the same problem. If not, I am going to close the topic.

Comment: Conceivably it could depend on the size of the labels being sent if you are sending every label together over the wire at once.  Generally, you will want to 'chunk' your printer communication into smaller bits, perhaps 4k at a time or so.

Comment: Hi Jason.How can I chunk the printer communication to 4k at a time?